# How to write DelegateCommand function parameters in VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I'm studying a WPF - MVVM project tutorial in C# and also i'm trying to write it in VB.

In ViewModel file (C#) the code is like that:

```
    public ICommand RemoveBookCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_removeBookCommand == null)
            {
                _removeBookCommand = new DelegateCommand<Book>(RemoveBook, CanRemoveBook);
            }
            return _removeBookCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanRemoveBook(Book book)
    {
        return Books.Count > 0 && Books.Contains(book);
    }

    private void RemoveBook(Book book)
    {
        Books.Remove(book);
        CurrentBook = null;
    }
```

And i convert it to VB like this:

```
    Public Property RemoveBookCommand() As ICommand
        Get
            If _removeBookCommand Is Nothing Then
                _removeBookCommand = New DelegateCommand(Of Book)(RemoveBook, CanRemoveBook)
            End If
            Return _removeBookCommand
        End Get
        Set(value As ICommand)

        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function CanRemoveBook(book As Book) As Boolean
        Return Books.Count > 0 And Books.Contains(book)
    End Function

    Private Sub RemoveBook(book As Book)
        Books.Remove(book)
        CurrentBook = Nothing
    End Sub
```

It seems there is no problem

But Visual Studio says:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'book' of 'Private Function CanRemoveBook(book As Models.Book) As Boolean'.
>
> Argument not specified for parameter 'book' of 'Private Sub RemoveBook(book As Models.Book)'.

It runs for C# when no 'Book' argument specified for functions. So, what's the problem in VB.net

Comment: You might want to set the property to `Public ReadOnly Property RemoveBookCommand() As ICommand` and then remove the `Set` part of the preoprty as it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
New DelegateCommand(Of Book)(AddressOf RemoveBook, AddressOf CanRemoveBook)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y72ewk2b(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: In addition, the equivalent to && in VB is 'AndAlso', not 'And'.